# listview data write onto csv file and then reading data from csv and displaying on listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, csv, export-to-csv

I have a form application on which multiple text boxes and list view given... I want to show list view data into csv file and then read data from csv and displayng onto listview. Code is given here... in this code m not getting desire output

```
private void btnUserInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView view=new ListView();
        string filepath=@"E:\Visual Studio Project\UserInfoTestApp\UserInfoTestApp\UserInfo.csv";
        InformationInsertion();
        ClearFields();
        ListViewtoCSV(view, filepath);

    }

    public void ListViewtoCSV(ListView lv,string path)
    {
        string Info ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < lv.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                Info += lvUserInformation.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text + ",";
            }
            Info = Info.TrimEnd(',');
        }           

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, Info);
        }
        File.AppendAllText(path, Info);
    }
```

plz write simple code which can be understand easily

[image]

Comment: `not getting desire output` could you be more specific?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. When you click on submit information you save the  strings in the csv file and then you want view all FirstName/LastName/Age in the dataGridView?

Comment: i want listview columns values to be write into csv file also when clik on submit perform... image is just given to show u form is like this.... otherwise my code has errors... i need u to write simple and understanble code so i can easily understand that how listview data store into csv file....

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood and i coded this:

```
  private void saveInCSVFILE()
    {
        if (txtName.Text != string.Empty && txtLastName.Text != string.Empty && txtAge.Text != string.Empty && txtAdress.Text != string.Empty && txtContactNumber.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filename.csv", true))
            { sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAge.Text, txtAdress.Text, txtContactNumber.Text)); }
            updateTable();
        }

    }
    private void updateTable()
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        dgv.Columns.Clear();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("filename.csv"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
            {
                string setRow = string.Empty;
                string[] tmp = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
                setRow = tmp[0] + ';' + tmp[1] + ';' + tmp[2];
                dgv.Rows.Add(setRow.Split(';'));
            }
        }
    }
```

1)If you want export this project never use the relative path but you must use the absolute path

2)I have used the using construct so the file will closed automatically when the loop is finished.

3)This isn't the best solution because every time that you call update table before it clear the table from column and row and after fill the dgv with the data.

Edit:

I think this is a better solution:

```
  private void SaveInCSVFILE()
    {
        if (txtName.Text != string.Empty && txtLastName.Text != string.Empty && txtAge.Text != string.Empty && txtAdress.Text != string.Empty && txtContactNumber.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filename.csv", true))
            { sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAge.Text, txtAdress.Text, txtContactNumber.Text)); }
            UpdateTable();
        }

    }
    private void UpdateTable()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("filename.csv"))
        {
            int tmpCountRow = 0;
            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
            {
                tmpCountRow++;
                if (tmpCountRow > this.rowCountFile)
                {
                    AddRow(sr.ReadLine());
                    this.rowCountFile++;
                }
                else
                    sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    private void ClearDataGridView()
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        dgv.Columns.Clear();
    }
    private void AddRow(string s)
    {
        string setRow = string.Empty;
        string[] tmp = s.Split(';');
        setRow = tmp[0] + ';' + tmp[1] + ';' + tmp[2];
        dgv.Rows.Add(setRow.Split(';'));
    }
    private void LoadTable()
    {
        ClearDataGridView();
        dgv.ColumnCount = 3;
        dgv.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "First Name";
        dgv.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Last Name";
        dgv.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Age";
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr=new System.IO.StreamReader("filename.csv"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
            {
                this.rowCountFile++;
                while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    AddRow(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this second solution I' ve implemented the function `LoadTable()` `AddRow(string s)` `ClearDataGrdView()` and I've edited `UpdateTable()`

1)The method `LoadTable()` will call in the form_load: this method fill your datagridview(dgv) with the data that were in the csv file. And this method save the line that are in the file

2)the method `AddRow(string s)` simply add a row in the dgv

3)the method `ClearDataGridView()` is called in the `LoadTable()`: clear the datagridview from rows and columns that are in that moment

4)the method `UpdateTable()` now is better because simply add the rows that before they aren't.